# How to configure .Net 4.5's JIT compiler?

Tags: .net, configuration, jit, .net-4.5

I've been having some problems with the .Net 4.5 JIT compiler. If I compile my assembly with JIT optimization disabled, it runs fine. If I don't, I get an Access Violation, Segmentation Fault, or some other weird error. (from completely managed code). It also only affects .Net 4.5

So, because we deal directly with IL, we really need to figure out what IL makes it crash (so we don't generate it). I'm suspecting(because it's multi-threaded code) that the new Multi Core JITting may be to blame. I'd like to narrow it down and get more information about it.

What kind of configuration options are there for the JIT compiler? Can I disable multi-core without disabling JIT compilation completely? Are there any other options I could use to try to track down what causes this?

Comment: There were a few optimizer bugs in the beta version.  So make sure you don't use the beta.  Other than that, a "segmentation fault" would be a bit of a miracle, that's a *nix message.  You'll need to describe the problem better to get an answer.

Comment: @HansPassant Segmentation fault also occurs in Windows? Basically, I have a console program and Windows will say "this program encountered a problem" etc etc, and in the console something like "Unhandled Exception: System.AccessViolationException ...." and below that it will print the managed stack trace(which is all managed code) Debugging in Visual Studio against the raw IL indicates it happens at a valid `stloc` instruction. The executable passes PEVerify. So, we're about 99% it's some bug with .Net 4.5's new JIT optimizations

Comment: You get no argument from me.  But if you can't get any help if you don't *document* the problem.  At this point we still don't even know what version of 4.5 you use.  Get help from Microsoft Support if you can't document it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a rather large project. I thought it was purely managed code, but apparently there was a few unmanaged parts. The problem ended up being we didn't properly mark some things as being marshalled, leading to memory being used by .Net 4.5 because it's more aggressive, but in .Net 4 and below, it'd be conservative and not use it "just in case"